# Im not able to edit content type fields, error An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: 2sxc

Im having this error when try to edit fields for a content type. Same problem when try to list items for a content field.

**"An item with the same key has already been added."**

**Stacktrace**

"   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)\r\n   at ToSic.Eav.WebApi.ContentTypeApi.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<GetFields>b__1(IContentTypeAttribute a)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.d__24.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.d__1b.MoveNext()"

Im still able to add or edit new items with buttons from template, and can add items from Data Tab.

I don´t know when the problem started because is possible to add or edit items, but today i tried to add a validation in some field and error appeared.

Any Idea what can be happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking a little bit into insights and I found that my Content Type had an attribute with duplicated key, I deleted the duplicated entry and started to work again, now im able to edit fields.

The problem for list all items was related with some Unicode characters into my string fields (emoticons), it appears unicode characters are not allowed in admin mode. Fields are being displayed normally in View Mode.

Comment: This sounds strange. Could you open an issue with an exact example how to reproduce?

Comment: Well is a little bit complicated, because I dont know when the problem started, so is not easy to try to reproduce. According to the insights, I checked the atributtes for type with problem, one by one, and the last one i added with type DateTime had two key with @DateTime Content-Type. and same Title, Target and Key. I deleted one of them and problem was solved.

Comment: ok, thx - in this case maybe you saved twice or something ran parallel. seems like a very edge case.

Comment: Definitely was a very strange case. I have added this case to my knowledge cases.